# display percentage progress of file_put_contents() to views Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently working on an uploading site. Here is my function for saving image name to database and uploading it to server from a base64 data.

```
public function addImages($order_last_id, $cropped)
  {
    // this is for saving the base64 image to database
    $order = $this->Order_model->get($order_last_id);
    // if(!$data){
    //   return false;
    // }

    //$images = [];
    $cropped_image = [];

    $date = new DateTime();
    $startdata = $date->format('YmdHis');
    $newName = str_replace('/', '', $startdata);
    $image_name =  $newName;
    $i = $this->db->insert_id();
      foreach ($cropped['cropped_images'] as $keys => $output){
        // $cropped_image[] = $output;
         $res[] = ['cropped_images' => $image_name.$i.".jpg", 
                  'order_id' => $order_last_id];
                  $i++;
      }

      // foreach ($data['name'] as $key => $image){
      //   $images[] = $image;
      // }

    // this is for uploading the base64 image to files
    $date = new DateTime();
    $startdata = $date->format('YmdHis');
    $newName = str_replace('/', '', $startdata);

      $image = [];
      $image_name =  $newName;
        $i = $this->db->insert_id();
        foreach ($cropped['cropped_images'] as $key => $value) {
        $image[] = $value;
        file_put_contents(
            "uploads/orders/".$image_name.$i.".jpg",
            base64_decode(
                str_replace('[removed]', '', $value)
            )
        );
        $i++;
      }

    return $this->db->insert_batch('orderimages', $res);
  }
```

now, What i want to do is display the file_put_contents() progress to my view. how can i Achieve that?

any help would be appreciated.

PS: I can't find anyting about this question on the net so I hope someone can help me

Comment: Storing the file with `file_put_contents()` should be more or less instant. On uploads, it's the uploading (the http request) that takes time, since it needs to send the complete file contents from the client to the server. The easiest way would be to use JavaScript (ajax) for that, which there are plenty of guides/tutorials for.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I am using file put contents to save High-res images (2mb and above) so I think it will also take more time for the images to be uploaded

Comment: No, that is fast (unless you have some issues with an _extremely_ slow file system, but that should rather be sorted out in that case). The upload time (the http request) will be magnitudes slower so that is what you should show in your view.

Comment: the purpose of this is my content took too much time to redirect after finished. so I wanna let the users know how much of their images are being uploaded to avoid reloading the page.

Comment: Oh I see. maybe I should start skimming my codes to know the actual source of delay. thanks for the response!

Comment: One more thing, the function in my controller have: saving data to database, sending emails to 2 recipients(user and admin) and file uploading to server using file_put_contents(). It took about a minute and half to execute this function. can you probably know what causes the most execution time?

Comment: From what you've posted, It's very unclear. You need to do some real debugging to find it out. However, you seem to have something called "cropped_images", are you doing some image manipulation? That can take considerable time depending on the size of the images, the specs of the server, the server load etc.

Comment: yup, I'm using image manipulation on Jquery.  btw thanks! really appreciate it man!

Comment: jQuery is front end so that wouldn't effect the upload speed or anything on the server.